# Get contiguous date ranges grouped into a single line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which holds a lot of rows (Currently, 500K, expected to rise to 15 Million in the next 3 years). The table holds payments made for a certain event for a specific day. And event can have 1 or many payments for the same day, but the payments on the same day must have different PaymentTypes.

Below is a table variable creation that creates the basic data (Input), and then a hardcoded select which is the expected output. I need to group continuous date ranges for a payment type, for a placement, in one row, with a From and To date, and then when there's a break - no rows, and then for the next date range.

For example:

Placement 1 got payments from the 1st to the 2nd (2 days) for Payment type 5, and then from the 4th until the 6th for the same type. Therefore, two rows. Payment type 1 also got a payment for the 1st to the 3rd for payment type 10. So, that is another row.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    PlacementId INT NOT NULL,
    PaymentTypeId INT NOT NULL,
    DateValue DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Amount DECIMAL(16,2) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Temp (PlacementId, PaymentTypeId, DateValue, Amount)
SELECT 1, 5, '01-JAN-2015', 100 UNION
SELECT 1, 5, '02-JAN-2015', 150 UNION
SELECT 1, 5, '04-JAN-2015', 78 UNION
SELECT 1, 5, '05-JAN-2015', 89 UNION
SELECT 1, 5, '06-JAN-2015', 22 UNION
SELECT 1, 10, '01-JAN-2015', 10 UNION
SELECT 1, 10, '02-JAN-2015', 10 UNION
SELECT 1, 10, '03-JAN-2015', 15 UNION
SELECT 2, 5, '01-JAN-2015', 200 UNION
SELECT 2, 5, '02-JAN-2015', 5 UNION
SELECT 2, 5, '03-JAN-2015', 50 UNION
SELECT 3, 5, '01-JAN-2015', 80 UNION
SELECT 4, 5, '07-JAN-2015', 100 UNION
SELECT 4, 5, '08-JAN-2015', 12 UNION
SELECT 4, 5, '12-JAN-2015', 66 UNION
SELECT 4, 5, '14-JAN-2015', 4 UNION
SELECT 5, 10, '08-JAN-2015', 10 

SELECT * FROM @Temp

SELECT 1 AS PlacementId, 5 AS PaymentTypeId, '2015-01-01' AS FromDate, '2015-01-02' AS ToDate, 250 AS Amount UNION
SELECT 1, 10, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-03', 35 UNION
SELECT 1, 5, '2015-01-04', '2015-01-06', 189 UNION
SELECT 2, 5, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-03', 255 UNION
SELECT 3, 5, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-01', 80 UNION
SELECT 4, 5, '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08', 112 UNION
SELECT 4, 5, '2015-01-12', '2015-01-12', 66 UNION
SELECT 4, 5, '2015-01-14', '2015-01-14', 4 UNION
SELECT 5, 10, '2015-01-08', '2015-01-08', 10
```

Note, there is a NCI on PlacementID and PaymentTypeID.

We're doing it at the moment with a crazy load of cursors, and are having extreme speed issues. (The 500K lines takes 4 minutes to process).

Is there an efficient method to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Yes, correct! Sorry. I'll fix that.

Comment: Also for `PlacementId = 1` and `PaymentTypeId = 10`, should the amount be equal to `35`, `10 + 10 + 15`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem called **Grouping Islands of Contiguous Dates**. Read this [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/) be Jeff Moden for more info.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/714/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PlacementId, PaymentTypeId ORDER BY DateValue), DateValue)
    FROM @Temp
)
SELECT 
    PlacementId,
    PaymentTypeId,
    FromDate = MIN(DateValue),
    ToDate = MAX(DateValue),
    Amount = SUM(Amount)
FROM Cte
GROUP BY PlacementId, PaymentTypeId, RN
ORDER BY PlacementId, PaymentTypeId, FromDate
```